# Using Owebia shipping extension Ceil value up to 10?

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping-methods, shipment

i'm using Owebia shipping extension for calculation shipping method but not work as follow

```
ceil ($value,10)
```

it's work when i use `ceil()`

**for example**    if i got total shipping charges  **60.540** it should be **70**  how could i do that ?
currently i'm using

```
{"pincoders2":{
"label":"StandardShipping",
"conditions":"in_array({shipto.postcode},array(695615,694564))"},
"id_016":{
"label":"ShippingDTDC",
"conditions":"({pincoders2.conditions})",
"fees":"ceil({cart.weight}*(150+150*.15))"}
}
```

**extesion reference** : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/owebia-shipping-free.html

**documentation** : https://owebia.com/os2/en/doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `ceil()` function worked for me.. I updated my question with answer

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, `ceil()` is just rounding to the nearest **integer**.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

If you want to round up to nearest fraction of 10, you can write a snippet to finish:

```
function ceil_up($float, $sig){
    return ceil($float / $sig) * $sig;
}
```

So in your case, `ceil_up(60.540, 10);` will return 70

Comment: i'm using owebia shipping configuration which use json so i cann't create php function for that..  i Used ceil() function working well but not solve my problem..

Comment: I teached you the concept on PHP. So back to the module, you may try to setup "fees" by `"ceil(({cart.weight}*(150+150*.15))/10)*10"`

Comment: thanks for you suggestion but it  would became unnecessary complex. simple ceil worked for me..